# Why am I not getting desired output when using fast scan function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates

I read in [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fast-io-for-competitive-programming/) and added the template to it so that it can work for every integer data types such as `long`, `long long` and `int`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void fs(T& x)     // For faster scanning of input
{  
    int n = 1;
    char c = getchar();
    x = 0;
    for (; (c < 48 || c>57) && c != '-'; c = getchar());
    if (c == '-') {
        n = -1;
        c = getchar();
    }
    for (; (c < 47 && c < 58); c = getchar())
        x = (x << 1) + (x << 3) + c - 48;
    x = n * x;
}

int main() 
{
    int test;
    fs(test);
    cout << test;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I tried executing it, the output is shown as `0` and not the input number. Is the above code wrong?

Comment: Unrelated: [What is a magic number, and why is it bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)

Comment: Notice that `<bits/stdc++.h>` is *not* a [standard C++ header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) (just an ugly implementation detail). So don't use it. Also, read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Please get a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/) and start reading if you want to learn C++ systematically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the output is shown as 0 and not the input number.

the test in

> ```
> for (;(c<47 && c<58);c=getchar())
> ```

is not the right one and must be

```
for (;(c>47 && c<58);c=getchar())
//      ^
```

Because of the error when you enter for instance `123` none of the *for* do something and *x* stay equals to `0`.

After the correction, compilation and execution (also adding `<<endl` in the *cout*):

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra cc.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
123
123
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
-123
-123
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Out of that to use the codes is not readable nor portable, better to do

```
for(;(c<'0' || c>'9') && c!='-';c=getchar()); 
...
for (;(c>='0' && c<='9');c=getchar())
```

and these *for* are more readable being *while*.

As signaled by @Basile Starynkevitch you can also use *[std::isdigit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)* to check if *c* is a digit or not, you would not have had your mistake using it.

Warning, if you reach EOF in the first *for* the code loops without ending, it is more secure to add `&& (c != EOF)` in it and for that to type *c* with *int* rather than *char*.

I also encourage you to no use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Both are same...

Comment: @Nick what you mean ? with `c>47` the code runs as expected

Comment: @nick Note the switched `<`-`>` in `c>47`

Comment: Oh sorry thanks..silly mistakes

Comment: `!isdigit(c)` is better than `c < '0' || c > '9'`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I wanted to be closer to the original code, I edited my answer to speak about it, after all the OP would not have made the mistake using it ;-)

Comment: `c` should be an int.

Comment: @RetiredNinja you are right, I read wrongly the code and supposed it was already, I edit my answer